# Covariance and orderby() issue

Tags: c#, expression-trees, covariance

Consider below code

```
public class CommentBll : IBaseBllPersistor<Comment>
    {
     public List<Comment> GetData<TProp>(Expression<Func<Comment, TProp>> selector)
    {         
        using (var context = new WebsiteContext())
        { 
            var query = (from q in context.Comment
                        select new CommentDto
                        {
                            ExtraProp = q.Name+q.Id.ToString(),
                            PostDate = q.PostDate,
                        }).OrderBy(selector);
            return query.ToList();
        }            
    }
    public class  CommentDto: Comment
    {
        public string ExtraProp { get; set; }    
    }
}

 public  class Comment: IBaseModel
{
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I remove this part from end of query

```
OrderBy(selector)
```

I get this error,

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<CommentDto> to System.Collections.Generic.List<Comment>
```

I know about covariance and I know the error is about it but why when I add `OrderBy(selector)` the error disappears?
Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Please show the *full* error message - the types that it's trying to convert from and to.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I edited the question

Comment: Hmm... I would expect that error to occur even with the `OrderBy`.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that the `OrderBy` you're using is not the `LINQ` method, as `OrderBy` does not change the type of the `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`. Could you please show us the type of `query` in the case that *does* work?

Comment: Actually, I'm sure of it - because `OrderBy(selector)` would not compile. You wouldn't be able to pass `Expression<Func<Comment, TProp>>` to the `OrderBy`, as it is expecting `Expression<Func<CommentDto, TProp>>`.

Comment: `}).OrderBy` has one `)` too many, making me doubt this code.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I remove some part of code because It was too long.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added some code and I think it's enough for someone who knows the answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas why this might be happening?

It's not so hard to be explained.

Let split your query in two parts:

```
var queryA = (from q in context.Comment
              select new CommentDto
              {
                  ExtraProp = q.Name+q.Id.ToString(),
                  PostDate = q.PostDate,
              });
var query = queryA.OrderBy(selector);
```

The type of `queryA` is `IQueryable<CommentDto>`.

Now, the type of the first generic argument of the `selector` is `Comment`. Since the `IQueryable<T>` is covariant and `Expression<TDelegate>` is invariant, the only way the compiler can satisfy your second query is to threat `queryA` as `IQueryable<Comment>`, hense the type of `query` is `IOrderedQueryable<Comment>`, and the final `ToList` call produces `List<Comment>`.

Apparently w/o the `OrderBy` you are calling `ToList` on `queryA` and the result is `List<CommentDto>`.

In the later case, the covariance of the `IQueryable<T>` allows easily getting the desired result by simply specifying explicitly the generic argument for the `ToList` call:

```
return queryA.ToList<Comment>();
```

Comment: Ah, well spotted. Hadn't thought about type inference on the `OrderBy` call. Doh. You might want to put the solution of just calling `ToList<Comment>` when the `OrderBy` isn't wanted.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. Actually more interesting is the similar case, but with `IEnumerable<TDerived>` and `Func<TBase,R>`, where the result is not obvious at all because of the `Func` first argument contravariance, so both results are equally possible. The (C#6) compiler picks the same as for `IQueryable<TDerived>` / `Expression<Func<TBase,R>>`, but I have no clue why.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean, but if you put up a new question with a complete example (so it's really easy to talk about) I'd be happy to try to flush it through the spec. Only if you're bothered though :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Not really - it is what it is, I can live with that :) It was nice to talk a bit with you though :)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the return type Comment with the ToList() as mentioned below

```
 return query.ToList<Comment>();
```

Comment: There's no need to do that. The OP can create a `List<Comment>` instead.

Comment: but return type is List<Comment> while you are returning List<CommentDto>

Comment: Which is why I'm suggesting the code is changed to actually return a `List<Comment>` - as per my answer. I'm assuming the signature is genuinely what the OP wants.

Comment: @MaheshChand I can't do that